# enabling Twig as Template Engine withing own plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I would like to integrate an Templating Engine (TWIG) within our custom plugin.

My question is:
how to handle/pass parameters which already are "echoing" its content.
for example:

```
echo $this->twig->render($file, ['val1' =>  settings_fields('settings')];
```

Comment: This is probably a question best posed to Twig's support channels

Answer (score 1):

I would use output buffering to capture the content, then pass that in to the template.

```
ob_start();
settings_fields('settings');
$settings_fields = ob_get_clean();
echo $this->twig->render($file, ['val1' =>  $settings_fields]);
```

I think that should work.

Comment: That is the approach, which I had used in our custom Template Engine. I thought there is more adequate way to handle it without the the output buffering functions.. nevertheless Thank you for your answer